# restarting delayed_job script via monit breaks /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, delayed-job, monit

So i am trying to use monit to monitor my delayed_job processes. And to do that, i have written this

/home/deploy/sites/app.project.com.my/shared/delayed_job.monitrc

```
check process delayed_job_0
  with pidfile /home/deploy/sites/app.project.com.my/shared/pids/delayed_job.0.pid
  start program = "/home/deploy/sites/app.project.com.my/shared/delayed_job.sh start staging 0"
    as uid deploy and gid deploy
  stop program = "/bin/su - deploy -c '/home/deploy/sites/app.project.com.my/current/bin/delayed_job stop staging 0'"
  group delayed_job
```

I have also written this script

/home/deploy/sites/app.project.com.my/shared/delayed_job.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
APP_NAME=app.project.com.my
APP_DIR=/home/deploy/sites
RAILS_ROOT=$APP_DIR/$APP_NAME/current
LOG_FILE=$APP_DIR/$APP_NAME/shared/delayed_job_monit.log

exec 2>&1


if [ "$3" ]; then
    RUNNER="$3"
else
    RUNNER=0
fi
echo "Runner: $RUNNER"


ENVIRONMENT=$2
echo "Env: $ENVIRONMENT"

PID_FILE=$RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids/delayed_job.$RUNNER.pid
echo "Pid: $PID_FILE"

cd $RAILS_ROOT
echo "Received $1"

function stop {
  cd $RAILS_ROOT
  RAILS_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT /usr/bin/env bin/delayed_job stop -i $RUNNER
}

function start {
  if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then 
    echo "Pid Found. Deleting PID FILE: $PID_FILE"
    rm -f $PID_FILE
  fi
  
  CMD=" /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=$ENVIRONMENT bin/delayed_job start -i $RUNNER"
  cd $RAILS_ROOT
  exec $CMD
}

case $1 in
  start)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  *)
    echo "WTF"
    ;;
esac
```

Now when in this folder `/home/deploy/sites/app.project.com.my/shared/`, if i run the delayed_job.sh script like this `./delayed_job start staging 0`. it works properly and the delayed_job is restarted.

But when i run the monit script `sudo monit start delayed_job_0`, i get an error `/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern`

Currently not sure how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: Yes. It feels like it is stuck on a process and that is all it prints

Comment: did you try to wrap the start command in `sh -c` also? Many errors I had at the beginning with not starting programs came from the missing environment, since the start command in monit does not set any.